# Find nearest node that satisfies a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have the following graph:

```
CREATE 
(a:SomeValue {name:'A'}), 
(b:SomeValue {name:'B'}),
(c:SomeValue {name:'*'}),
(a)-[:CHILD_OF]->(b),
(b)-[:CHILD_OF]->(c),
(c:SomePath {path:'A-B'}), 
(c)-[:FROM]->(a),
(c)-[:TO]->(b),
(d:SomePath {path:'*-*'}),
(d)-[:FROM]->(c),
(d)-[:TO]->(c)
```

Let's say I'm looking for a Configuration where `(path)-[:FROM]->(b)` AND `(path)-[:TO]->(b)`.

Clearly in my graph there is no `'B-B'` path, so I would like some kind of fallback search that looks for the presence of `'*-*'` which is the default path.

Basically what I'm trying to say is: look for a `(path)-[:FROM]->(b)` , if there isn't one, get the nearest *SomeValue* `x` binded to `b` via the `CHILD_OF` relationship that satisfy a `(path)-[:FROM]->(x)` relationship.

Is there a way to express this with Cypher?

Answer (score 0):

dierre,

I think you can accomplish this with a UNION.

```
MATCH p=(b:SomeValue)<-[:FROM]-(a:SomePath)-[:TO]->(b)
RETURN p
UNION
MATCH p=(b:SomeValue)<-[r:CHILD_OF*]-(c:SomeValue)<-[:FROM]-(a:SomePath)-[:TO]->b
RETURN p
```

Grace and peace,

Jim